# How to schedule a Task Scheduler to run every increment and not be confused by Day Light Savings time?

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler, time-zone, repeat-rate

I am using the Windows 7 Task Scheduler to run a task once and repeat every 1442 minutes (24 hours plus two minutes).  Today, due to Day Light Savings time change, it ran an hour early.

How can I configure it in the Task Scheduler to properly adjust for Day Light Savings time and run an actual 1442 minutes later?

I notice there is a check box entitled: "Synchronize across time zones".  Would this do the trick?  I've checked it but won't know until we Fall back whether it has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is an impossible mission. Consider that days on daylight saving time change don't have 24 hours. In local time one day may be 23, 24, 25 hours long. AFAIK the windows scheduler doesn't know the term 'hours in one day of local time'. That's what you need.